# How do i anticipate setstate and calling API in the same function because setstate is async

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i need some help with setstate asynchronous.

i have this select

```
<select id='province'  onChange={handleProvince}>
                    <option>Select Province</option>
                    {province?.map(province=>(
                        <option value={province.id}>{province.name}</option>
                    ))}
 </select>
```

and this is the onchange function

```
function handleProvince(e){
    setProvinceID(e.target.value)
    axios.get(`http://192.168.18.46/api/regency/${provinceID}`).then((res)=>{
      setRegency(res.data.data)
    })
  }
```

putting the `setProvinceID(e.target.value)` in the same function causes me to change the select element twice for it to pick the value.

how do i anticipate it?

any help would be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: so i put ```setProvinceID(e.target.value)`` in the useEffect, and set the provinceID as dependencies?

Comment: Never do this, **Never set in a useEffect hook a dependency of the same hook** you'll send the browser into a frenzy. A dependency useEffect should set a state depending on another state or set of states but not itself. @pandu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the async call from the eventHandler and use it as a dependent a useEffect hook, everytime the provinceID gets set, the call is made right after.

```
// I imagine this is what your state declaration looks like
const [provinceID, setProvinceID] = useState("");

function handleProvince(e){
    setProvinceID(e.target.value)
 }

useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`http://192.168.18.46/api/regency/${provinceID}`)
    .then((res)=>{
      setRegency(res.data.data)
    })
}, [provinceID])
```

I had imagined that you were working with a react functional component also what your state declaration would be like, both inference made from your use of `setProvinceID`.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like it:

```js
const handleProvince = ({ target }) => (
    axios.get(`http://192.168.18.46/api/regency/${target?.value}`).then(({ data }) => {
      setProvinceID(target.value);
      setRegency(data?.data);
    })
  );
```